# Solution of nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the general solution to the following partial differential equation

$$\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{w^{4}}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}-1\right)^{2}}.$$

I started with the substitution

$$t=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x},$$

leading to

$$t^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{w^{4}}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-w^{2}}}-1\right)^{2}},$$

which is not easy to solve. However, there might be a more straightforward way. Thanks for your help.

Remark: Sec. 2.2.4.7 of Handbook of non-linear partial differential equations (Polyanin, Zaitsev, 2011), [page 90](https://books.google.cz/books?id=tAfLBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Handbook%20of%20non-linear%20partial%20differential%20equations&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q=Handbook%20of%20non-linear%20partial%20differential%20equations&f=false), claims that the solution of

$$\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=f(w)$$

leads to the complete integral in implicit form of

$$\int\frac{dw}{\sqrt{f(w)}}=\pm\sqrt{(x+c_{1})^{2}+(y+c_{2})^{2}}.$$

Comment: Use the [Lagrange-Charpit method](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~ymori/docs/teaching/math8402/spring14/lagrange_charpit.pdf) for fully nonlinear first order PDEs (see from equation (9) onwards).

Comment: @mattos: Thank you very much!